# What is the Ubuntu 16.04 package for vim with python3 support?

Tags: 16.04, python, python3, vim

I want to install a vim version that supports python3 (`+python3`), but I am unable to find it on the Ubuntu repositories.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.7, and I can't upgrade to 18.04 currently because I need my system stable for work.

Is it possible to install a vim package from the Ubuntu repositories that includes python3 support?

Before I build it from source, I want to make sure there is not a package already.

Comment: Thanks for the link, @muru. Unfortunately, it doesn't answer my question. Ubuntu 16.04 is supposed to support python3, but it doesn't seem to. I am going to build vim so that I can force python3 support.

Comment: Which vim packages did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer I could find was to build vim myself with +python3.